# How to Use State inside the function in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, state

I got this error when I call **this.state.testState** inside a function.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

```
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);

        this.state = {
            testState: 'hello'
        }

    }

    render(){
         function testing(){
            let testState123 = this.state.testState
             //some codes
            return testState123;
         }


         return(
              <div>
                   {testing()}
              </div>
         );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: just alias or bind your function. `let testState123 = this.state.testState; function testing()...` or if you bind. `const testing = () => {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` keyword is undefined inside your `testing` function. This is just one of the many nuances of React. Typically, in traditional vanilla JavaScript, the `this` keyword  refers to the closest object that is one level higher than the context it is used in (without binding).

However, in React you use classes instead, and when defining a method, like you did, the `this` keyword does not implicitly bind to your component's execution context. Instead, the `this` keyword is `undefined` because there is no higher object that owns this component.

There are a couple of ways to solve our problem and they all revolve around binding the `this` keyword to your component.

You could explicitly bind the function in your constructor, which will point the `this` keyword to your component's context.

```
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            testState: 'hello'
        }
        this.testing = this.testing.bind(this)
    }

    function(testing){
       let testState123 = this.state.testState
       //some codes
       return testState123;
    }

    render(){
         return(
              <div>
                  {this.testing()}
              </div>
         );
    }
}
export default Home;
```

Or your can use an arrow-function, which has lexical-binding. Which essentially just means that the function you defined inherits the overarching context of its parent. In this case, it is the class component.

```
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            testState: 'hello'
        }
    }

    testing = () => {
       let testState123 = this.state.testState
       //some codes
       return testState123;
    }

    render(){
         return(
              <div>
                  {this.testing()}
              </div>
         );
    }
}
export default Home;
```

Worth noting, its a good rule-of-thumb to declare your `methods` outside of `render` as a means of separating logic from mark-up.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function or another to bind "this"

```
 const testing= ()=>{
          let testState123 = this.state.testState
           //some codes
          return testState123;
       }
```